# What are the best packages for decoding/encoding MIME headers (base64)?

Tags: ruby, base64

I am trying to encode/decode MIME headers in Ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby has Base64 methods in core, just do

```
require "base64"
```

and use `Base64.decode64` and `Base64.encode64`.  For quoted-printable, you could use the following code [here](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/133587).

Answer (score 0):

If the mime content is related to emails you might also want to check out TMAil...

http://tmail.rubyforge.org/

It has a nice approach to parsing out email attachments and multi-part messages and what not.