# Decoding a string

Tags: ruby, base64

I found out that many files on my web server contain these inputs:

```
K3SQCI5YoWjgHwLacjuuWrKs7yE=
yEw5FOQQ1LFUa3aBbKQJLqXTVGo=
```

I need to figure out the encryption type or what these inputs are.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the best packages for decoding/encoding MIME headers (base64)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373149/what-are-the-best-packages-for-decoding-encoding-mime-headers-base64)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a base64 encoded string, not an encrypted string.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: The strings seem to contain more than four types of characters. They cannot be base4 encoding.

Comment: @Sudhir It is not written so.